# Is there a limit to the length of the command you can send over an SSH channel/connection using Paramiko SSHClientInteraction?

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko, send

I'm new to Paramiko and have tried a variety of methods for doing what is a pretty basic task.  At this point, all I'm trying to do is execute a command on an APC UPS.  In my testing, I discovered I can successfully execute a command, as long as the length of the command is 20 characters or less.

Here is my code -

```
import paramiko
from paramiko_expect import SSHClientInteraction

host = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"  # UPS
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(hostname=host, username='e164468', password='********', banner_timeout=60)

chan = SSHClientInteraction(ssh, timeout=2, display=True)
prompt = 'apc>'
command = 'cipher -rsake disable'
chan.expect(prompt)
chan.send(command)
chan.expect(prompt)
output_raw = chan.current_output_clean
chan.close()
ssh.close()
print ("Here is your output - ")
print(output_raw)
```

The command I need to remotely execute is 'cipher -rsake disable'. What I get in the terminal when I run this is -

```
apc>cipher -rsake disablEXCESS TIME RECV_READY TIMEOUT, did you expect() before a send()
```

If I drop the disable parameter from the command, it works as expected.  No matter what I've tried, I get this behavior whenever the command is over 20 characters.

I'm not sure how valid of a test it is but I manually ssh to the UPS and can type in whatever command I need and it works.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you test other 20 character long commands?

Comment: Yes I did but once I hit 21 characters, I get that error.

Comment: Try `print(chan.channel.send(command + "\r"))` – what does it say? Does it print correct number of bytes sent (including the new line)?

Comment: Consistently prints the number of characters in the command + 1 so yes, it looks correct.

Comment: I just tried running the same script against one of our Cisco routers and I can successfully pass commands greater that 20 characters.  I found the source for ```SSHClientInteraction``` at https://github.com/fgimian/paramiko-expect/blob/master/paramiko_expect.py             Line 165 is where the error I'm receiving comes from.  I'm not able to connect the dots between the behavior of my script and the source code but I'm starting to wonder if it's something with SSH running on the APC UPS.

Comment: Well, it's definitely not a limitation of the Paramiko or `SSHClientInteraction`. It's something either on the server-side or between the Paramiko/`SSHClientInteraction` and the server.

Comment: Ok well thanks for your input.  I'll make an attempt to contact APC (server-side) and see if that gets me anywhere.